# Assert on bootstrap angular alert when using protractor and cucumberJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, ui-automation, cucumberjs

I am using protractor , cucumberJS and chai-as-promised.

I have a message (bootstrap alert of angularJS) that appears in DOM when a button is clicked on. It completely disappears from DOM after 6000 ms.

I was trying to assert that the expected message string has appeared.

This is how it looks in the DOM :-

```
<div style="text-align: center; margin: 10px 0px;" class="alert alert-success ng-scope" ng-show="postOrSaveSuccMsg != ''" ng-if="postOrSaveSuccMsg != ''">
            <a class="alert-link ng-binding" href="#">Archived successfully.</a>
        </div>
```

Would anyone kindly help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my problem by using:

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
```

Before attempting to get the message.

Regards,

Comment: Try applying the same with your problem. @karishma

Comment: I have tried this already, but it does not work probably because I am using CucumberJS and not Jasmine. I believe, that is the reason, I am unable to access protractor specific methods and its global objects/functions as well. If you have any clue about this, please let me know. @Jesus Lopez